# Dynamically creating buttons in DOJO

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to learn DOJO using JS fiddle.

I want to write a code where buttons are created (I know the code to create buttons, now).

But I want to make this dynamic with a loop, which creates n number of buttons. And n is a number that is defined (like 2,3 .. )

Answer (score 2):

That's Simple task , you have just to iterate with for / while loop

and use programatic Button creation and PlaceAt widget function to place created button inside a parent elemnt (here div element )

See below snippet : or this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/p6kb8uge/)

```js
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom-construct", "dijit/form/Button"], function(dom, ready, domConstruct, Button) {
  ready(function() {
    
    var number =  prompt("Please enter a number",3)

    for(var i=1 ; i<= number; i++) {
      new Button({
         
        label: "Button n°"+i,
        onClick: function(){
            alert('I\'m a Button');
        }
      }).placeAt("btnContainer");
      
    }    
    
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">

  <div id="btnContainer"></div>

</body>
```